# Binding to a class member

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

This one seems to be basic and somehow it can be duplicated but no one of the answers I found on the internet made the thing work for me ..

I want to bind elements from my UI (XAML) to members of instances of classes I have. 
So, lets have a simple XAML

```
<Window x:Class="gUSBampReader.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="601" Width="857" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:binding;assembly=binding">

   <TextBlock Name="UITextBlock"/>  <!-- THIS IS THE TEXT BOX TO BE BINDED -->

</Window>
```

And on the other side I have a class

```
public class foo
{
    objectThatImplementsINotify a; //lets say that's equivalent to an string
}

public partial class mainWindow : Window
{
    public foo externalMembers;

    public mainWindow()
    {
       externalMembers = new foo();
       //Let's show externalMembers.a in UITextBlock!
    }
}
```

I would like to learn how to do this binding both from XAML and from C#. Because some times external members is there and I can bind at developing time but other times is dynamic and it must be created and binded in execution time

And finally .. can you recommend a good tutorial on dataBinding with some examples ? There is a lot of stuff for XAML (but I've been unable to make it work). But not too much for C#.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to set the DataContext of your window to itself:

```
public mainWindow()
{
   externalMembers = new foo();
   DataContext = this;
   //Let's show externalMembers.a in UITextBlock!
}
```

And then you need to bind the textblock:

```
<TextBlock Name="UITextBlock" Text="{Binding externalMembers.a}"/>
```

To make it work you further need to change `externalMembers.a` to be a property, not a field:

```
public class foo
{
    objectThatImplementsINotify a { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man!! It really works !!  Any clue on how to do it from C# ??

Comment: That's another question. Please post it as such.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, binding only works with properties, not with fields. Please see this for additional details, including how to create the binding in code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300.aspx. You should change your classes to use properties instead of fields.

Comment: Usefull link! 
I acepted the other question just because it was more explicit and detailed, but thanks !!